# Algorithm to price bulk discounts

Tags: algorithm

i am designing a Chinese auction website.

Tickets ($5, $10 & $20) are sold either individually, or via packages to receive discounts.
There are various Ticket packages for example:

1. 5-$5 tickets = receive 10% off
2. 5-$10 tickets = receive 10% off
3. 5-$20 tickets = receive 10% off
4. 5-$5 tickets + 5-$10 tickets + 5-$20 tickets = receive 15% off

When users add tickets to their cart, i need to figure out the cheapest package(s) to give them. the trick is that if a user adds 4-$5 tickets + 5-$10 tickets + 5-$20 tickets, it should still give him package #4 since that would be the cheapest for him.

Any help in figuring out a algorithm to solve this, or any tips would be greatly appreciate it.

thanks

**EDIT**

i figured out the answer, thanks all, but the code is long.

i will post the answer code if anyone still is interested.

Comment: I had to lookup "Chinese auction" to see if it was a well-known auction system, or if you were just writing your website in Chinese. Turns out that it's the former: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_auction :)

Comment: In your example, would they get 10% off the $20 tickets only?  Or 10% everything?  Or 10% off any tickets with a quantity > 5?

Comment: @Jeff B the would get 10% whatever is in that package, so if i were to add 6-$20 tickets, i would get 10% off 5 of them

Comment: And you can qualify for multiple non-overlapping packages? So, if I buy 3-$5 6-$10 and 5-$20, I would pay $15+$55+$90 = $160?

Comment: @High Performance Mark, i am leaning towards sorting the packaged by sum(qty) desc, then loop through the packages recursively adding the combination's to a list. once we figure out the correct price i will cache those results to a table, so then next time some adds the same QTY, we will already know what packages to give him

Comment: @Jeff B, in that case you would pay $158.75 (we would give him package #4 - even though he doesnt need the extra 2-$5 tickets - for $148.75, + the additional $10 ticket for $10)

Comment: Ah, so your example should say that you give him package #4, not package #3.

Answer (score 1):

After selling the customer as many complete packages as possible, we are left with some residual N of tickets desired of each of the 3 types ($5, $10, $20). In the example you gave, the quantities desired range from 0 to 5 (6 possible values). Thus, there are only 214 possible residual combinations (6 ** 3 - 2; minus 2 because the combinations 0-0-0 and 5-5-5 are degenerate). Just pre-compute the price of each combination as though it were purchased without package 4; compare that calcuation to the cost of package 4 ($148.75); this will tell you the cheapest approach for every combination.

Is the actual number of packages so large that a complete pre-computation wouldn't be a viable approach?

Comment: This seems like a good approach in general.  I tried to come up with a greedy algorithm, but I was able to find a case in which that gave the wrong answer.  You should take into account the possibility that combinations of the 10% packages might be better for given demands than the 15% package; consider 5x$5, 5x$10, 4x$20.

Comment: @Chromatix Yes, "purchased without package 4" was intended to include the idea that you would sell someone packages 1, 2, or 3 whenever their residual order included quantities of 5. Your 5-5-4 example would be $147.50 without package 4 (package 1, package 2, plus 4 individual $20 tickets), which is cheaper than package 4.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is dynamic programming.

The idea is that if the buyer wants x of item A, y of item B, and z of item C, then you should compute for all triples (x', y', z') with 0 <= x' <= x and 0 <= y' <= y and 0 <= z' <= z the cheapest way to obtain at least x' of A, y' of B, and z' of C. Pseudocode:

```
for x' = 0 to x
    for y' = 0 to y
        for z' = 0 to z
            cheapest[(x', y', z')] = min over all packages p of (price(p) + cheapest[residual demand after buying p])
            next_package[(x', y', z')] = the best package p
```

Then you can work backward from (x, y, z) adding to the cart the packages indicated by next_package.

If there are many different kinds of items or there are many of each item, branch and bound may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate how many full Package 4s you need. Get them out of the way.

```
full_package_4_count = min(x, y, z) mod 5.

x = x - 5 * full_package_4_count
y = y - 5 * full_package_4_count
z = z - 5 * full_package_4_count
```

Now, there may still be worth buying some more Package 4s, even though they didn't actually want to buy that many tickets.

How many of them could there be?

```
partial_package_4_max = (max(x, y, z) + 4) mod 5
```

Now loop to try each of these out:

```
best_price = 10000000
for partial_package_4_count = 0 to partial_package_4_max:
    -- Calculate how much we have already spent.
    price = (full_package_4_count + partial_package_4_count) * 175 * (1-0.15)

    -- Work out how many additional tickets we want.
    x' = max(0, x - 5 * partial_package_count)
    y' = max(0, y - 5 * partial_package_count)
    z' = max(0, z - 5 * partial_package_count)

    --- Add cost for additional tickets (with a 10% discount for every pack of 5)
    price = price + x' mod 5 * 25 * (1-0.10) + x' div 5 * 5
    price = price + y' mod 5 * 50 * (1-0.10) + x' div 5 * 10
    price = price + y' mod 5 * 100 * (1-0.10) + x' div 5 * 20

    if price < best_price
        best_price = price
        -- Should record other details about the current deal here too.
```

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if there was a way to do this without looping.

If performances was a factor, I would pre-calculate it with every possible combination up to 100 tickets, or whatever amount would never happen on your site.